# What are the Gravitational PE conventions for setting the zero point at infinity?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, potential-energy

If you set the zero point at infinity (the edge of the universe), is the gravitational PE still zero at a distance $\infty \pm r$? Or would you make it a $0 \pm (-Gm_1 m_2/r)$? Basically, is infinity plus/minus r still infinity?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Infinity is not a number, so you cannot add anything to it. Usually what we really mean by $\infty$ is a number that is much larger than relevant numbers of the system.

Comment: @AaronStevens infinity as in an infinite distance away from the center of the system.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}-G\frac{m_1 m_2}{R^2}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{R\to \infty}-G\frac{m_1 m_2}{(R\pm r)^2}=0$$
So it is still zero as you go a distance of $r$ away from $\infty$, at least insofar as that idea makes sense.